Problem writing to a Control from another class and another thread
I have code that, using UDP, broadcasts the letter "P" to an Arduino WiFi.
It should broadcast 3 times with 3 seconds interval and then stop.
To monitor this, I want to see the broadcast messages sent and the messages returned from the Arduino in a RichTextBox.
As I want to a more complex program, I want to structure it and have therefore put the SendWifiString method in a class called WifiTools (which eventually will include a receive method).
I use a System.Timers.Timer to start the broadcasts, so its Elapsed event is raised in a ThreadPool Thread. In the Elapsed event handler, I generate a custom event to then write to the RichTextBox.
I have also added a button to make a broadcast for debugging.
If I test this using "Start Without Debugging" everything works fine, I see the broadcast messages in the RichTextBox, but if I use "Start Debugging" I get a "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer broadcastTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public int broadcastCounter = 0;
    private delegate void RichText(string text);
    WifiTools wifiTools = new WifiTools();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartBroadcastTimer(1000);
        wifiTools.OnRichText += WifiTools_OnRichText;
    }

    public class RichTextEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string? Msg { get; set; }
    };

    public void WifiTools_OnRichText(object? sender, RichTextEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += e.Msg;
    }

    class WifiTools
    {
        public event EventHandler<RichTextEventArgs>? OnRichText;
        public void SendWifiString(string sendString, string _ipAddress, int port)
        {
            try
            {
                UdpClient udpClientSendWifiString = new(_ipAddress, port);
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendString);
                udpClientSendWifiString.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
                string richTextBoxMsg = "\nTX: to      " + _ipAddress + ":" + port + "   Msg: " + sendString;
                OnRichText?.Invoke(null, new RichTextEventArgs { Msg = richTextBoxMsg });
            }
            catch
            {
                OnRichText?.Invoke(null, new RichTextEventArgs { Msg = "Wifi Send Fail" });
            }
        }
    };

    public void StartBroadcastTimer(int broadcastInterval)
    {
        broadcastTimer.Interval = broadcastInterval;
        broadcastTimer.Start();
        broadcastTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Broadcast!);
    }

    private void Broadcast(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string broadcastAddress = "192.168.1.255";
        int remotePort = 23921;
        wifiTools.SendWifiString("P", broadcastAddress, remotePort);
        broadcastCounter++;
        broadcastTimer.Interval = 3000;
        if (broadcastCounter > 2)
        {
            //Stops timer and releases all resources (this timer is only used at program start)
            broadcastTimer.Dispose(); 
            broadcastCounter = 0;
        }
    }     

    private void buttonBroadcast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string broadcastAddress = "192.168.1.255";
        int remotePort = 23921;
        wifiTools.SendWifiString("P", broadcastAddress, remotePort);
    }
}

The exception originates from the catch statement, and occurs in the WifiTools_OnRichText() method.
If I comment out the code in the catch block:
OnRichText?.Invoke(null, new RichTextEventArgs { Msg = "Wifi Send Fail" });

then debug runs without problem, but noting is written in the RichTextBox. But I can see on my Arduino that the broadcasts were sent.

You're accessing a Control from a Thread other than the UI Thread, so you should change the code in the event handler to BeginInvoke(()=> richTextBox1.AppendText(e.msg);. Or replace the timer with a System.Windows.Forms.Timer, its Tick event is raised in the UI Thread

What research have you done? The first google hit for the exception was another SO question, the second: How to make thread-safe calls to controls (Windows Forms .NET)

Thank you Jimi, BeginInvoke did the trick. I thought I did this by the book by invoking OnRichText from my class object, but his obviously was not the case.

And JonasH, I did look before at the reference you sent, but I did not see it as a response to the question of calling from another object. Actually, I used this solution with my first try which I did before putting SendWifiStrin in an class.

If you're referring to OnRichText?.Invoke([...]), that just invokes the event delegate, i.e., it raises the event. Control.BeginInvoke() (asynchronous) or Control.Invoke() (synchronous) have a different meaning; in practice, these marshal the call to the UI Thread using the implicit WinForms SynchronizationContext. Prefer BeginInvoke() (non-blocking) when you don't really need to wait for the action delegate to return. Much better when handling this kind of callbacks. The Timer you're using now, for example, could spawn another Thread when the callback blocks the current

If you want to notify a commenter , use @ before the name. But what Jimi said. Note that multi threading is difficult, and you need to know some of the potential problems and solutions. The compiler is of little help for avoiding threading bugs, and many are much nastier than a simple Cross-thread operation error.

Thank you for your explanation Jimi, it makes things clearer to me.

@JensM — Sorry, I cannot see your question. The question marks can be found only in your code samples. Your code does not look reasonable to me, some things look redundant (why timer?), but I cannot confidently judge it, because you don't explain your ultimate goals ("I want to structure it" does not explain any motivation), nor do you explain a problem.

@Sergey A Kryukov - You're right that I did not use a question mark, but I obviously wanted to get rid of the "Cross-thread operation not valid" which both Jimi and JonasH understood. And they provided me with the answers I needed, so you don't need to bother. But thank you for your attention.

@JensM — Thank your answer. I was almost ready to answer because I know well how to work with cross-thread operations, but I wanted some clarifications. In this case, it would be good to close this question. Could you do that?

@Sergey A Kryukov - I don't know of a method to close a question, I rather got the impression that the question and answers should remain available for others having similar questions.

@JensM — I have no a way to close the question, too. I only know that you could accept an answer, but you don't have answers yet, and you may never get one. But you could delete it. I am not quite agree with the value of this question for others. It is contaminated with unrelated details. You need to create a short self-contained reproducible code sample focusing on exactly one issue, then it may work.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (but I would add some more items).
